"event : nua_r_register status : 503 phrase : DNS Error" from sofia-sip in Android Client
I have cross compiled sofia-sip for Android and trying to register a sip server but getting 503 DNS error.
I have followed the reference documentation. Sharing the code snippets and logs below:
typedef struct context context;
#define NUA_MAGIC_T struct context

typedef union operation operation;
#define NUA_HMAGIC_T  operation


#include <sofia-sip/nua.h>
#include <sofia-sip/sip_util.h.>
#include <sofia-sip/su_log.h>
#include <sofia-sip/sres_sip.h>
#include <sofia-sip/sresolv.h>
#include <sofia-sip/su_alloc.h>

struct context {
    su_home_t home[1];
    su_root_t *root;
    sres_resolver_t *sres;
    sres_query_t *s_query;
    nua_t *nua;
};

typedef union operation {
    nua_handle_t *handle;
    struct {
        nua_handle_t *handle;
    } call;

    struct {
        nua_handle_t *handle;
    } subscription;
} operation;

Starting sofia-sip and registering
std::string proxy = "sip:sip.linphone.org";
std::string username = "someuser";
context s_ctx[1] = {{{{(sizeof s_ctx)}}}};
operation *op = (operation *) su_zalloc(s_ctx->home, (sizeof *op));

su_init();
su_log_init(su_log_default);
su_log_set_level(su_log_default, 9);
su_log_redirect(su_log_default, custom_logger, stdout);

const char *resolvConfContents = env->GetStringUTFChars(resolv_content, NULL);

std::string tempFilePath = "/data/data/com.honeywell.healthcare.systevo/files/resolv.conf";
FILE *tempFile = fopen(tempFilePath.c_str(), "w");
if (tempFile) {
fputs(resolvConfContents, tempFile);
fclose(tempFile);
}

su_home_init(s_ctx->home);
s_ctx->root = su_root_create(&s_ctx);
if (s_ctx->root == NULL) {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sofia-SIP", "%s", "Failed to create root");
return -1;
}

s_ctx->nua = nua_create(s_ctx->root, nua_callback, s_ctx, TAG_NULL());
if (s_ctx->nua == NULL) {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sofia-SIP", "%s", "Failed to create nua");
return -1;
}

op->handle = nua_handle(s_ctx->nua, op, TAG_NULL());

s_ctx->sres = sres_resolver_create(s_ctx->root, tempFilePath.c_str(), TAG_END());
if (s_ctx->sres == NULL) {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sofia-SIP", "%s", "Failed to create resolver");
return -1;
}

nua_set_params(s_ctx->nua,
                   NUTAG_MEDIA_ENABLE(1),
                   SIPTAG_ALLOW_STR(
                           "INVITE, SUBSCRIBE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, PRACK, MESSAGE, UPDATE, NOTIFY, INFO"),
                   NUTAG_USER_AGENT("UserAgent/1.0"),
                   NUTAG_ENABLEMESSAGE(1),
                   NUTAG_ENABLEINVITE(1),
                   NUTAG_AUTOALERT(0),
                   NUTAG_SESSION_TIMER(0),
                   NUTAG_AUTOANSWER(0),
                   NUTAG_EARLY_MEDIA(0),
                   NUTAG_EARLY_ANSWER(0),
                   NUTAG_AUTOACK(1),
                   NTATAG_UDP_MTU(1700),
                   TAG_NULL()
);
su_root_step(s_ctx->root, 1000);

nua_set_params(
            s_ctx->nua,
            NUTAG_PROXY(proxy.c_str()),
            NUTAG_REGISTRAR(proxy.c_str()),
            NUTAG_M_DISPLAY(username.c_str()),
            SIPTAG_FROM_STR("sip:someuser@sip.linphone.org"),
            TAG_END()
);
su_root_step(s_ctx->root, 1000);

nua_register(
            op->handle,
            NUTAG_REGISTRAR(proxy.c_str()),
            NUTAG_AUTH_CACHE(nua_auth_cache_challenged),
            SIPTAG_EXPIRES_STR("4000"),
            TAG_END()
);
su_root_step(s_ctx->root, 4000);

log output
nua.c:621 nua_register() nua: nua_register: entering
nua_stack.c:559 nua_signal() nua(0x76445d8840): sent signal r_register
nua_params.c:484 nua_stack_set_params() nua: nua_stack_set_params: entering
soa.c:280 soa_clone() soa_clone(static::0x764909a000, 0x76490212c0, 0x76445d8840) called
soa.c:403 soa_set_params() soa_set_params(static::0x764909a200, ...) called
soa.c:403 soa_set_params() soa_set_params(static::0x764909a200, ...) called
nua_dialog.c:338 nua_dialog_usage_add() nua(0x76445d8840): adding register usage
nta.c:4497 nta_leg_tcreate() nta_leg_tcreate(0x764901e500)
nta.c:2716 nta_tpn_by_url() nta: selecting scheme sip
sres_cache.c:272 sres_cache_get() sres_cache_get(0x76490214c0, NAPTR, "sip.linphone.org.") called
nta.c:10537 outgoing_query_naptr() nta: for "sip.linphone.org" query "sip.linphone.org" NAPTR
sres.c:981 sres_query() sres_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490a7f00, NAPTR, "sip.linphone.org") called
sres.c:2743 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1a80) called
sresolv.c:190 sres_sofia_update() sres_sofia_update(0x764901e380, 102, -1)
sres.c:2832 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1a80) id=13974 NAPTR sip.linphone.org (to [127.0.0.1]:53)
sres.c:3273 sres_resolver_error() sres_resolver_error(0x76490435e0, 102) called
sres.c:3430 sres_resolver_report_error() sres: network error 111 (Connection refused) from 127.0.0.1 by icmp type=3 code=3 reported by 127.0.0.1
sres.c:3073 sres_resend_dns_query() sres_resend_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1a80, error) called
sres.c:3000 sres_query_report_error() sres(q=0x76490b1a80): reporting error NETWORK_ERR for NAPTR sip.linphone.org
sres_cache.c:272 sres_cache_get() sres_cache_get(0x76490214c0, SRV, "_sip._udp.sip.linphone.org.") called
nta.c:10738 outgoing_query_srv() nta: for "sip.linphone.org" query "_sip._udp.sip.linphone.org" SRV
sres.c:981 sres_query() sres_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490a7f00, SRV, "_sip._udp.sip.linphone.org") called
sres.c:2743 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1b60) called
sres.c:2832 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1b60) id=13975 SRV _sip._udp.sip.linphone.org (to [127.0.0.1]:53)
sres.c:3073 sres_resend_dns_query() sres_resend_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1b60, error) called
sres.c:3000 sres_query_report_error() sres(q=0x76490b1b60): reporting error NETWORK_ERR for SRV _sip._udp.sip.linphone.org
sres_cache.c:272 sres_cache_get() sres_cache_get(0x76490214c0, AAAA, "sip.linphone.org.") called
nta.c:10862 outgoing_query_aaaa() nta: for "sip.linphone.org" query "sip.linphone.org" AAAA
sres.c:981 sres_query() sres_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490a7f00, AAAA, "sip.linphone.org") called
sres.c:2743 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x76490435e0, 0x76490b1a80) called
sres.c:2822 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(): sendto: Connection refused

but if i do the query separately with custom resolver i created using resolv.conf file, i am getting answers
const char *domain = "sip.linphone.org";
    s_ctx->s_query = sres_query(s_ctx->sres, process_dns_response, NULL, sres_type_a,
                                     domain);
    if (s_ctx->s_query == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Sofia-SIP", "%s", "Failed to create query");
        return -1;
    }
    su_root_step(s_ctx->root, 4000);

log output
sres.c:981 sres_query() sres_query(0x75ee86a640, 0x0, A, "sip.linphone.org") called
sres.c:2743 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x75ee86a640, 0x7644588360) called
sresolv.c:190 sres_sofia_update() sres_sofia_update(0x75ee86f400, 101, -1)
sres.c:2832 sres_send_dns_query() sres_send_dns_query(0x75ee86a640, 0x7644588360) id=22348 A sip.linphone.org (to [8.8.8.8]:53)
sres.c:3479 sres_resolver_receive() sres_resolver_receive(0x75ee86a640, 101) called
sres.c:3795 sres_create_record() ANSWER RR received sip.linphone.org. A IN 8028 rdlen=4

somehow the sofia-sip is not using the custom resolver i created but it is using the default one, your help is much appreciated here.
